# Synchronize data with facebook and twitter

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to know how i would be able to synchronize data (news and events) with a facebook page.

For example, I have a web site called abc.com (with a news and events section), and a  facebook page called facebook.com/abc. I would like to know how i could synchronize the news and events from abc.com with facebook.com/abc. Whenever the administrator manages news and events, the data should automatically update itself on its facebook page.

Could anyone kindly guide me or even post some URL's that would help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the following services,

[ping.fm](http://ping.fm)

[hellotxt](http://hellotxt.com)

They are providing API for that.. From that, you can update many social networking sites at once.

Just register with any of these services and the API to update the status at the end of the script where u add/upload things or stuffs..